# Call Ajax Function Based on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jquery ajax to search for something using a third-party api. Once it find something, it returns a bunch of data to the screen. What I'm trying to do is call the `search` function depending on the URL and I'm a not familiar with handling dynamic URLs with Ajax.

For example, if I search for `shoes` via a button, the URL should change to `localhost/search=shoes`. But if I actually type that same URL into the address bar, it should call the `search` function with a query of `shoes`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I can handle this?

```
var search = function( query ){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax base url' + query,
        data: {
            q: query,
            // etc
        },
    }).done( function(){
      console.log('Do something with data');
    });
};

$('.btn-search').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = $(this).text();
        search( data );
});
```

Comment: Hard to understand what you want: an AJAX URL is any arbitrary valid URL BUT it must be on the same server as the JS has been loaded from ("same origin policy"). Issuing whatever against a remote api on a foreign server causes an exception in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with regexp if the string is the full url or just the query, the most simple example can use this regex: `localhost\/search=(.*)`.

To use this regexp you should use [String.match](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/string/match) function

After that you should call the function depends on the query with [switch](http://devdocs.io/javascript/statements/switch) statement

Answer (score 0):

You can set the URL by simply

```
window.location = "localhost?search=shoes";
```

If you visit this page, you can check for URL get parameters in document.ready using GetURLParameter helper function

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var search = GetURLParameter("search");

    if(search){

      console.log('Do something with data');
    }
});

function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}​
```